# Will it be called augmented reality if I render a reality-based 3D model instead of render a camera view?

Tags: mobile, augmented-reality

I've developed an application, and now I wonder if my work can be regarded as [augmented reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality):

Instead of overlap something on a camera preview, I build and render 3D buildings on a mobile phone. These models are the same (or similar to) some real buildings. I use GPS and gyros to decide the player's position and heading, so that I can render an animation with specified orientation so that the image will "look like" an image captured by the phone camera.

Then I can perform some games related to the real world. For example, I can make 3D models for restored Athenian ruins. When you go Athens and point your phone to the ruins, you'll see its original state on the screen. An early demo video: http://youtu.be/YIX3oZi1O_o

Can I define my application as a kind of augmented reality game, according to general meanings of augmented reality? If not, is there any proper term that can describe my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the academic papers applications like this are known as "situated simulations", see the work of Gunnar Liestøl: http://inventioproject.no/sitsim/

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's exactly what I'm seeking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, the general definition of Augmented Reality is "Taking real time real world input, and adding a layer on top of this to augment (change) this reality". With real time world input usually a camera is meant.

Your idea sounds more like a simulation, since you simulate everything, the only input you receive from the real world is position.

Of course broadly speaking you might still consider your application to be AR, but I wouldn't put it on the box art.